# Set icon of non app mac os x bundle

Tags: macos, icons, bundle

How to set icon for bundle which is not an app? I tried using CFBundleIconFile, but it doesn't work (though if I just change bundle extension to `.app`, icon is changed to desired one). Is there another key, or the only way is to set icon for directory? If so, is there already some script to do this from command line (Xcode run script)?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Visual documentation of the process of copying and pasting an icon in the Finder]

If you need to do it from CLI...  It's a bit more involved...

First, you need to add a `CFBundleIconFile` string to your bundle's

```
YourThing.bundle/Contents/Info.plist
```

> Here's where the developer gets to
>   specify a custom icon for the bundle.
>   This key contains the name of a file
>   in the bundle's Resources folder that
>   holds the icons. TextEdit keeps its
>   icon in a file called Edit.icns file,
>   but there's no rule about what the
>   name of the file must be.

That said, you either need an ICNS file, or can [follow these instructions](http://www.amnoid.de/icns/makeicns.html) from this [Utility (which includes its source code)](http://www.amnoid.de/icns/makeicns-1.1.zip) that generates ICNS's from image files via the command line..

```
$ ./makeicns
```

> Usage: makeicns [k1=v1] [k2=v2] ...
>
> Keys and values include:
>       512: Name of input image for 512x512 variant of icon
>       256: Name of input image for 256x256 variant of icon
>       128: Name of input image for 128x128 variant of icon
>        32: Name of input image for 32x32 variant of icon
>        16: Name of input image for 16x16 variant of icon
>        in: Name of input image for all variants not having an explicit name
>       out: Name of output file, defaults to first nonempty input name,
>            but with icns extension
>
> Examples:

```
  makeicns -512 image.png -32 image.png
```

> Creates image.icns with only a 512x512 and a 32x32 variant.

```
  makeicns -in myfile.jpg -32 otherfile.png -out outfile.icns
```

> Creates outfile.icns with sizes 512,
>   256, 128, and 16 containing data
>         from myfile.jpg and with size 32 containing data from otherfile.png.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer from similar (duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362063/icon-for-mac-osx-bundle/14515666#14515666):

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
  setIcon:(NSImage *)image
  forFile:(NSString *)bundlePath
  options:0];
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, however it didn't change the file inside `/Contents/Resources/appicon.icns` in my app bundle. Even if i restart it uses the new icon i set it to, but my old image remains in the Resources folder, making me think some tricky stuff is going on other then a simple refresh. Can you please share your thoughts on this @yairchu

Comment: @Noitidart: I found it in the duplicate question (linked) as I mentioned. "Fruity Geek" gave the answer over there and links to Apple's reference, I don't have any further details..

Comment: This is like doing it from the Get Info window in Finder. It doesn't change the icon file in the bundle. It won't persist when moving to another machine will it?